# How do I find html codes on wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When I view the page source, the code snippet I encounter is as follows;

[image]

I searched inside the wordpress to get the html codes that appear here but I couldn't find it.

I can't find a file ending with .html in the theme or plugin editor. Is Wordpress html files hidden? Where can I find it if it is not hidden?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just open that `<head>` tag? Or scroll down? I don't understand the question. Anyway, right-click and then "show source-code" should work. Wordpress uses php files not html. Everything you see here should be in the source-code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are not html files in wordpress, not normally at least, all the worpress pages are built in php, so if you have access to the editor you'll see a lot of .php, .js and .css files, here you can edit whatever you need, about the theme or functionalities, but not the content, to edit the content all you have to do is go to the pages section and select the page you need, or the posts section and select the post you need to edit.

Same with the wordpress plugins, you go to the editor in the plugins section and there you'll see .php, .js and .css regularly, there you can edit whatever you need but be carefull because you can break your website.

If you still don't get how then is the html sent to the users, wordpress use php as backend language, with the php files, wordpress generates html depending on what you have done in the admin dashboard.

If you need anything else let me know, happy to help

Comment: Thanks for enlightening Martin. 
For example, let's say I want to put a button on a photo. Is this possible with php?

Comment: it is, but it is easier just writing html or using a plugin in the admin dashboard, so, let's say that you need a button in the "us" page, you go to pages > us and there you'll see an html tab, there you can write any html as you want so you would write "<button></button>" and so, dame for the posts, if your case is more complex than this, give me a way to contact you and i can help you more in private

Comment: It would be great if you help me. You can contact me on twitter. username = @KesenAlican

Answer (score 0):

Thats because that content is not stored in .html files.

I think u are looking for:
../wp-content/themes//header.php
../wp-content/themes//footer.php
etc.

or mayby an other .php-file in the folder:
../wp-content/themes//

Comment: Thank you i will try. Frankly I don't know much php :(